# Full width block within bootstrap <Container> component;

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have my `<Container>` somewhere up in the tree. In an abstract component like `<MainLayout>`

Something like

```
<div className="d-flex flex-column vh-100">
   <Header />
   <Container className="flex-grow-1">{children}</Container>
</div>
```

Then in one of components, I have a `<SubHeading>` component which should span to the full width.
I could deal with the fact that `<Container>` adds paddings for every screen size. I would just add negative margins for my `<SubHeading>` component. The issue I cannot solve is that `<Container>` also has fixed `max-width` and `margin: auto`. Meaning at some point negative margins will not be enough and my `<SubHeading>` component would start to have blank spaces from left and right. (See the image attached)
[image: marging auto causes extra space]

I cannot really split it somehow because then my reusable MainLayout will not have any padding meaning it will lose one of its main responsibilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the default padding/margin on sides for containers, you can use the `container-fluid` class instead of `container`. That spans it to a 100% of screen width on all sizes. [Bootstrap Fluid Containers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/#fluid-containers)